# Add a Custom Order Attribute to API Response

Tags: magento2, api, custom-attributes, api-response

I am trying to add a custom attributes to Magento API service. I did some research and follow this link

https://meetanshi.com/blog/get-value-of-custom-attribute-on-magento-2-rest-api/

However, my API respond not showing the custom attribute, what did I do it wrong? I had a custom field inside the sales_quote table. Is it just works like a modulo? do I need to create registration.php to set this up as well? or do you have any other recommendation that I can foloow?

Answer (score 0):

I found out I need to write a custom Module to let this thing enable